# How to inform the link of a scheduled online meeting in formal emails?

Tags: formal-language, email

I am writing a formal email to someone to send him the link of a scheduled online meeting. I have already acknowledged him before about the meeting. I can not figure out the most appropriate and formal way to say "Here is the link for tomorrow's session"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said,

> I have already acknowledged him before about the meeting

I suspect that you meant "informed" rather than "acknowledged".
The expression you use, "Here is the link for tomorrow's session." seems fine as it is, but you could relate your email to your previous discussion of the meeting:

> "Here is the link to the meeting to be held at 10:30 AM tomorrow, that we discussed yesterday:
>   http:link.cyberspace.universe
>   I look forward to your participation."